# How to use a Timer to Show a Form in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0, desktop-application

I'm trying to show a form after a period of time (the app is a tray app). For this I'm using a Timer, and on the Elapsed method I show a form that simply displays a message to the user (kind of like a notification).

The problems seems to be that I can only use ShowDialog(), otherwise if I use Show(), the form simply freezes as soon as it's open. I would like to use Show(), because normally the user could click the message in the notification and open the menu or other forms of the application and if I use ShowDialog(), then I must open the other forms with ShowDialog() aswell and it does not seem like a good practice.

I put some simple code below to demonstrate the issue:

```
internal static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        Application.Run(new AppContext());
    }
}

public class AppContext : ApplicationContext
{
    public AppContext()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new (5000);
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => Elapsed();
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Elapsed()
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

All the forms shown simply freeze immediately. If I put ShowDialog() instead they will work fine.

Comment: Wrong Timer, use System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead.  Now the Tick event runs on the main thread and Application.Run() can keep it alive.  Do keep in mind that the odds that the user cannot see the form are high, covered by whatever app they are using at the time.  Favor NotifyIcon to attract the user's attention.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to have fixed the problem. I have a NotifyIcon but I just put some code to exemplify the problem as simply as possible.